# DHCP List not empty after disconnection

Tags: wireless-router, dhcp

I have a wimax modem connected to a router, a TP LINK router, the weird problem I am having is that it keeps dropping wifi, and I cannot reconnect to the wifi again. I connected the router by wire, to look into the problem, and the DHCP Client list, shows my laptop as still connected! I am suspecting that this is what keeps it from connecting again, but how is this happening? And what can I do to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

DHCP clients are allocated leases that last for some period of time. If lease time not expires and client not send DHCP Release you view entry in "DHCP Client list". To view the actual alive the host on the network, you can watch the presence of ARP record.
To quickly remove obsolete entries from the lease database, you can specify a shorter DHCP Lease time, for e.x 60 sec, on TP-Link by default it came as 1440 minutes, which is 24 hours.

Comment: you're probably right, which means my problem lies elsewhere